# JQuery back button (goes to blank page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have implemented a button:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <li class="ui-body ui-body-b ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-last-child">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-corner-all">Submit</button></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="cancelButton" data-direction="reverse" type="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-corner-all">Cancel</button></div>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with accompaning JavaScript function that should make the button act as a "back" button:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#cancelButton', function() { 
      window.history.back();
});
```

All I'm testing at the moment is a transition between two pages, and the button works fine for the first three transitions. On the third transition, instead of going back one page, it goes to a blankpage (I believe this is created by my IDE, NetBeans). When I use the console to call `window.history.back()` it transitions nicely and does not have any issues whatsoever. My question is if there is some interaction between the button and the `window.history.back()` call that males it go to a blankpage

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you're not taken back to the blank page, check if history really exists before firing back action:

```
if (history.length > 1) {
    history.go(-1);
}
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, using `window.history.back()` (as would `history.go(-1)`) in the console works for whatever reason but using in the function above does not. The history element when running the application always has a length above 1

Comment: Make `console.log()` fire based on events that are happening on the page to debug it. It's hard to tell like this. Otherwise post non-working example to  jsFiddle, so we could try.